# How to decode MySQL text with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

How in this example I can encode text from MySQL?

This is how the text look like in MySQL using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`:
    $text = 'Wiesław';

I have tried so far:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");

echo htmlentities($text);
echo '</br>';
echo html_entity_decode($text);
echo '</br>';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
echo '</br>';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($text, ENT_NOQUOTES);
echo '</br>';
echo utf8_encode($text);
echo '</br>';
echo utf8_decode($text);
echo '</br>';
echo mb_convert_encoding($text, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
echo '</br>';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $text);
echo '</br>';
echo mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Results:

```
Wies³aw
Wies³aw
Wies³aw
Wies³aw
WiesÂ³aw
Wies?aw
Wies?aw

WiesÂ³aw
```

Expectation:

Wiesław

Answer (score 1):

Grrr.. Don't use any of those functions.  Instead, configure MySQL correctly.

Good:  `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` -- That's a "Collation"; it implies the `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

- Have `UTF-8` characters in the client.  (Obviously, you do since you have a stoke-l).
- Tell MySQL that the client is using `utf8mb4`.  It is best to do this when establishing the connection.  PHP has `mysqli` and `PDO`.  Details for each:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#php
- Declare the columns (and optionally the table and database) to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see if that is OK now.

If after doing that, you get

```
WiesÅ‚aw  -- Mojibake
Wies?aw   -- question mark
Wies      -- truncation
Wies�aw   -- black diamond
```

Then go to [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for further advice and debugging.

The hex should be `57 69 65 73 C582 61 77`.
If you get `57 69 65 73 C385 E2809A 61 77`, then you have "double encoding".

Answer (score 0):

If you're text is coming in HTML format, the following command should work:

```
mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

OR

```
mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ISO-8859-1'));
```